# Why stl vector can't contain coroutine objects?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, stl, coroutine

I use coroutine in boost1.53, see my code below:

```
boost::coroutines::coroutine<int()> f(std::bind(foo, ...));
std::vector<decltype(f)> container; // it can be compiled
container.push_back(f); // compile error
```

the error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<boost::coroutines::coroutine<int(),0> >::vector(paracel::coroutine<int>&)’
```

Update: The error is occured because there are no copy construction/operator in 'boost::coroutines::coroutine', case here is I only want to save the 'f's into a container which map a index to 'f'.

I also tried unordered_map, and emplace_back, it still can not work!

How can I make it work in C++?

Update2:
I tried vector,unordered_map, map together with emplace_back, push_back, std::move and all failed.
But list and deque is ok with push_back/emplace_back and std::move:

```
std::deque<decltype(f)> container1;
container.push_back(std::move(f)); // ok
std::deque<decltype(f)> container2;
container.emplace_back(std::move(f)); // ok
std::list<decltype(f)> container3;
container.push_back(std::move(f)); // ok
std::list<decltype(f)> container4;
container.emplace_back(std::move(f)); // ok
```

Why?

Answer (score 8):

It looks as if `boost::coroutines::coroutines<int()>` doesn't support a copy constructor. You try to `push_back()` an lvalue, however. You might want to try moving the object into vector, though:

```
container.push_back(std::move(f));
```

Comment: If the type you want to put into a vector is neither copyable nor movable, it won't work. You'll need to use a different container, e.g., `std::deque<...>` or `std::list<...>` and `emplace_back()` the objects.

Answer (score 3):

If you check e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) you will see that the contained type

> T must meet the requirements of [CopyAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable) and [CopyConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyConstructible).

And

> The requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the container. Generally, it is required that element type meets the requirements of [MoveConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveConstructible) and [MoveAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable), but many member functions impose stricter requirements.

If you check the [`coroutine` class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/coroutine/coroutine/coroutine.html) you will see that it has neither copy-assignment operator nor a copy-constructor. It *do* have move variants of those, but as noted by the second paragraph above, it's not always enough.

Comment: @xunzhang: I'm not sure it's sufficient, but using `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` would probably be a start.

Answer (score 1):

I use Boost 1.54 and it works for me with both g++4.8.2 and clang-3.4 with libc++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/coroutine/coroutine.hpp>

typedef boost::coroutines::coroutine<int()> coro_t;

void f(coro_t::caller_type& ca)
{
   ca(42);
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<coro_t> coros;
   coro_t foo(&f);
   coros.push_back(std::move(foo));
   coros.emplace_back(&f);
   for(auto& coro : coros)
      std::cout << coro.get() << std::endl;
}
```

I'm going to speculate that you don't have a working standard library or the move assignment in coroutine of boost 1.53 is not noexcept (you can check that with `std::is_nothrow_move_assignable`).

Answer (score 0):

two possibilities:

1.) allocate the coroutines on freestore:

```
std::vector< shared_ptr< coroutine< void >::pull_type > v;
v.push_back( new coroutine< void >::pull_type(...) );
```

2.) use a moveaware-container ([boost.container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/move/move_and_containers.html)):

```
boost::container::vector< coroutine< void >::pull_type > v;
coroutine< void >::pull_type c(...)
v.push_back( boost::move( c) );
```